# TypeError: _ReanimatedModule.default.configureProps is not a function

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-reanimated-v2

Please I am facing this error currently in my expo app, is there anyone that can help please, I just upgrade our app to expo / SDK 46.0.0, React native 0.69.6, and I was forced to upgrade to reanimated 2.9.1. thereby bringing this error every time I run npm start —clear, I have imported it in barbel.config.js as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/2.2.x/installation/). thank you.

complete error

```
  ERROR  TypeError: _ReanimatedModule.default.configureProps is not a function. (In '_ReanimatedModule.default.configureProps(Object.keys(NATIVE_THREAD_PROPS_WHITELIST), Object.keys(UI_THREAD_PROPS_WHITELIST))', '_ReanimatedModule.default.configureProps' is undefined)
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
```

Please help thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Expo SDK version 49 or later, it requires Reanimated version 3. Expo SDK 49 introduced support for Reanimated 3 and made it the default version. If you are using Reanimated version 2.*, it may not work properly with Expo SDK 49 or later, and you may encounter compatibility issues and errors.

Answer (score 1):

**Steps to solve this issue:**

1. Check your **package.json** file and look for 'react-native-reanimated' package. if not available then add the latest version.
2. Check your **babel.config.js** and add the following

   module.exports = function (api) {
   api.cache(true);
   return {
   presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
   **plugins: ["react-native-reanimated/plugin"],**
   };
   };
3. Then we need to clear the cache, run the following command: **npx expo start -c**

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is the ***babel.config.js*** file.
You need to change the content of that file to

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: ["react-native-reanimated/plugin"],
  };
};
```

That solved the same problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

i was facing same error  on   "react-native-reanimated": "^3.3.0", what works for me was to uninstall react-native-reanimated

```
npm uninstall react-native-reanimated
```

and install the latest version

```
npm install react-native-reanimated
```

and it works using  "react-native-reanimated": "^3.6.1",

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same error after upgrade Expo from 44 to 47. the problem occur coz of `react-native-reanimated` version. so u need to try set version to @2.10.0 then flow these steps
[here](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/next/fundamentals/troubleshooting#multiple-versions-of-reanimated-were-detected) then problem will be gone

Answer (score 0):

```js
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      // Required for expo-router
      'expo-router/babel',
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin'
    ],
  };
};
// npx expo install expo-router react-native-safe-area-context react-native-screens expo-linking expo-constants expo-status-bar react-native-gesture-handler
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/guides/troubleshooting/#mismatch-between-javascript-part-and-native-part-of-reanimated) this **usually happens when Reanimated is not properly installed**, e.g. forgetting to include the Reanimated Babel plugin in babel.config.js.

The solution is also documented [here](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/getting-started/#step-2-add-reanimateds-babel-plugin)

**Step 1**
Install react-native-reanimated package from npm:

`npx expo install react-native-reanimated`

**Step 2**
Add react-native-reanimated/plugin plugin to your babel.config.js.

```
    presets: [
      ... // don't add it here :)
    ],
    plugins: [
      ...
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ],
  };
```

**Step 3**
Step 3: Clear Metro bundler cache (recommended)

`npx expo start -c`

**Step 4**
Restart you app by running:

`npm start`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues when trying to install and use react-native-reanimated. If you have followed the [documentation](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/getting-started/#step-2-add-reanimateds-babel-plugin) as mentioned in other responses and you are still facing issues, ensure that you have the latest expo SDK and the compatible versions of any libraries you are using. This is generally important to keep your app running without any unexpected errors.

The procedure is straightforward following the expo documentation [here](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/#sdk-changelogs).

**1. Upgrade the Expo SDK**

```
npm install expo@latest
```

**2. Upgrade dependencies**

```
npx expo install --fix
```